# Google Play Pre-registration: What if I haven't launch my game on Google Play within the limited 90 days?

Tags: google-play, registration, launch

I noticed the official introduction said that "If you haven't launched within 90 days in any of these countries, your pre-registration campaign will be terminated in all countries and new pre-registration campaigns can't be started."

My question is if there is any influence on those players who had already pre-registered my game? Can they still receive the launch notification or download the game automatically?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Sel Tu Hi, did players receive your game notification when launched after pre registration ended ?

Answer (score 0):

Your app's Pre-registration page will be removed from Google Play.
the users who already pre-registered will receive notification when you finally release the app.

Comment: If I haven't launch my App with 90 days, does Google Play Console will turn my app from pre-regitration into launch automatically?

Comment: No they will not